# Reloading grand parent window while parent is already closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a parent window(#1) which opens a popup child window(#2) which in turn opens a popup child window(#3). While (#3) is opened, (#2) is closed by self.close().

My question is when I close (#3) how do I refresh (#1)? I tried window.opener.opener.reload(), but since (#2) was closed already, this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Once the #2 window is closed, you lose reference to it, hence you can't refer to its opener (#1) to refresh it.

**However**, judging by a quick test in Chrome console, pass reference of window #1 down to window #3 document and use it later on to reload it. It might look like this:

```
// in window #1 - opening window #2
var win2 = window.open('samedomainurl...');

// -----------------
// in window #2 (just opened)
// -----------------
// open window 3
var win3 = window.open('samedomainurl...');
// pass reference to window.opener (which is #1) to newly opened win3 document
win3.document.grandparentWindow = window.opener;

// -----------------
// in window #3 - after closing #2 you still can access #1 using document.grandparentWindow property
// -----------------
// reload original window
document.grandparentWindow.location.reload();
```

Comment: I have added win3.document.grandparentWindow = window.opener; in #2 after creating #3. After that i have closed #2. In my #3 i have used document.grandparentWindow.location.reload(); self.close(); But the grandparent window did not reload and #3 not closed. I did not get any error. I think, things got stuck in document.grandparentWindow.location.reload();

Comment: Check if you really have #1 window available in your #3 - try to alert `document.grandparentWindow` (in #3) if it returns undefined that something is off elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
window.parent.opener.location.reload();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".